# Django Channels listening TCP/UDP

Tags: django, python-3.x, tcp, django-channels

I have a GPS tracker that communicates with TCP protocol. The data will be send to web client via Websocket. I also need to persist it to database.

I intent to use Django as my main framework for this. But the problem is the TCP protocol.

Can django channel listen to TCP/UDP protocol?? Or should I use asyncio and then send it to django channels applications via ASGI??